# Create new tag with nested tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can we create a new tag with nested tags by using BeutifulSoup?

For example, given the following HTML:

```
html = """
   <div id="root">
   </div>
"""
```

The desired output would be, for example:

```
html = """
   <div id="root">
      <div id="child">
         <div id="grandchild">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite an involved code, but that's how it can be done:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
   <div id="root">
   </div>
"""
# parse the root
root = BeautifulSoup(html)

# create the child
child = BeautifulSoup('<div id="child" />')

# create the grandchild under the child, and append grandchild to child
grandchild = child.new_tag('div', attrs={'id': 'grandchild'})
child.div.append(grandchild) 

# create the child under the root, and append child to root
root.new_tag(child.html.contents[0].div)
root.div.append(child.html.contents[0].div)
```

Note that:

- if you print `root`:

  ```
   [...]
   print(root.prettify())
  ```

  the output is:

  ```
   <html>
     <body>
        <div id="root">
           <div id="child">
             <div id="grandchild">
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </body>
   </html>
  ```

  meaning that `root` is now a full HTML document.
  So if you want to use `root` as a div, make sure you access it as such, using `root.div`.
- The last line (`root.div.append`) empties `child`, so that if you print it after executing that last line:

  ```
  [...]
  print(child.prettify())
  ```

  the output is:

  ```
  <html>
    <body>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can append another `soup` to a tag. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
   <div id="root">
   </div>
"""

to_append = '''
  <div id="child">
     <div id="grandchild">
     </div>
  </div>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
soup.select_one('div#root').append(BeautifulSoup(to_append, 'html.parser'))
print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<div id="root">
 <div id="child">
  <div id="grandchild">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```